# How to get model_id from Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to convert Rails model class name to a symbol :model_id? For example, I'm trying to convert class Book to book_id. Now I'm able to do it with

```
"#{Book.to_s.parameterize}_id".to_sym
```

is there better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certainly other ways to do it. They're not necessarily better:

```
Book.name.foreign_key.to_sym
```

You'd also need to consider what you want to happen if the class is in a module e.g. `Library::Book`.

```
Library::Book.name.parameterize.foreign_key.to_sym
=> library_book_id
```

Comment: `Book.name` is the same as `Book.model_name`? or you meant some property of model?

Comment: `name` is a method on `Module` (and therefore `Class`) that returns the name of the module. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-name

Comment: Thanks. I just tried to warn, that if there is a `name` property of Rails model `Book` it mainly will be called. So, i prefer to use `model_name` property instead.

Comment: Any one knows how to convert it back from model_id to model?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer something like:

```
Book.model_name.parameterize('_').foreign_key.to_sym
```

As parametrize default separator is `-`. Link [parameterize](http://apidock.com/rails/String/parameterize) [foreign_key](http://apidock.com/rails/String/foreign_key)